# parsed json data sorting reversed

Tags: jquery, json

I managed to parse json data and loop this data into select option tag. But the data is sorting reversed. This is my json file:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"key": "First","value": 100},
    {"key": "Second","value": 200},
    {"key": "Last","value": 300}
  ]
}
```

and this is my html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url:'example.json',
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(item){
            $.each(item['items'], function(i,n){
              option = '<option value="'+n['value']+'">'+n['key']+'</option>';
              $("#show-data").after(option);
            });
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option id="show-data" value="" selected disabled>Please select an item</option>
    </select>
  </body>
```

and this is the result:

[image]

is there a way so the data is sorted correctly?

Comment: i have followed your suggestion, but only "Last" item that showed @kukkuz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because in each iteration you insert the new `option` element direct `after()` the first one, and therefore in front of any previous added.

To fix this, instead call `append()` on the `select` itself:

```js
// dummy AJAX data
var item = {
  "items": [{
    "key": "First",
    "value": 100
  }, {
    "key": "Second",
    "value": 200
  }, {
    "key": "Last",
    "value": 300
  }]
}

// in AJAX callback
$.each(item['items'], function(i, n) {
  var option = '<option value="' + n['value'] + '">' + n['key'] + '</option>';
  $('select').append(option);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option id="show-data" value="" selected disabled>Please select an item</option>
</select>
```

You could also improve performance of this by creating all the new options in a single string and calling `append()` once:

```
var options = '';
$.each(item['items'], function(i, n) {
  options += '<option value="' + n['value'] + '">' + n['key'] + '</option>';
});
$('select').append(options);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `.after()` new elements are inserted after the element in iteration. Hence on completion it in reverse order.

You can create a string then use `.after()`

```
var options = '';
$.each(item['items'], function(i, n) {
  options += '<option value="' + n['value'] + '">' + n['key'] + '</option>';
});
$("#show-data").after(options);
```

However, I would recommend you to specify `ID` attribute to `select` element, then use `.append()`

*HTML*

```
<select id="show-data">
  <option  value="" selected disabled>Please select an item</option>
</select>
```

*Script*

```
$.each(item['items'], function(i, n) {
  var options += '<option value="' + n['value'] + '">' + n['key'] + '</option>';
  $("#show-data").append(option);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could as well do just:

```
$.each(item['items'].reverse(), function(i,n){
```